# Fields in CakePHP could not be referred by JQuery

Tags: cakephp

I have got a simple HTMl form with one field as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="data['User']['user_id']" id="data['User']['user_id']" value="1"> 


$(document).ready(function(){
$("#data['User']['user_id']").mouseover(function(){
alert("hello");
});

});
```

The code couldn't work, 
I think it may be the name of the Input text field that caused the problem,
but I don't know how to alter it 
because this is the naming convention in CakePHP.

Comment: The problem being that the javascript does nothing? JQuery appears to be unable to find the item specified in your selector?

Comment: why not make the `id` just a simple string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) has the answer:

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters (`#;&,.+*~':"!^$[]()=>|/`) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, if you have an an input with `name="names[]"`, you can use the selector `$("input[name=names\\[\\]]")`.

So in your case: `$("input[name=\\[User\\]\\[user_id\\]]")`

Note though that I think the HTML snippet you posted is bogus. By default the Cake form helper creates elements like this:

```
<input type="text" name="data[User][user_id]" id="UserUserId" value="1">
```

The name does not contain any `'` and the id is camelCased to be easily selectable.

Comment: Oh yes you are right, deceze.
I have made a big mistake in my question.
It should be name="data[User][user_id]"
Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that

```
$("#data[User][user_id]")
```

is telling jQuery to look for the element with

```
id="data[User][user_id]"
```

, not

```
name="data[User][user_id]"
```

Not sure though, someone correct me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JQuery is pretty dumb about matching things that have brackets in the matching text. Use the following as your selector:

```
 $("[id^=data['User']['user_id']]")
```

It uses the ^= comparison operator for "starts with", which seems to work for me.

Comment: Say I got another Input text field named like this
name="data['User']['username']"
The old code you suggested: $("[name^=data['User']['user_id']]")
will raise another problem

When I moved my mouse over the second field, the alert popped up too.